# Make AWS S3 ACL public for public bucket/file?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I can see the ACL for [this](https://collidr-api.s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/pfd.RDS) file with:

```
aws s3api get-object-acl --bucket collidr-api --key pfd.RDS
```

but I don't think others can see the ACL (even though the file itself is public).

Is there a way to make the ACL public?

Comment: Out of interest, why do you want the ACL itself to be publicly readable? PS your awscli example is missing the object key.

Comment: @jarmod Thanks for the `key` pickup. Reason why is because I created [this](https://github.com/cloudyr/aws.s3/issues/316) (unrelated) issue a while ago, but when I ran the code in the issue myself just today, I only then realised that (it appears) others don't actually get a response from R's `aws.s3::get_acl()` function (when I wrote the issue, I had thought ACL's were public if the object was public). In other words, I thought ACLs were public, but it appears they aren't. I'm not sure if that can be changed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can provide public (unsigned) access to get an object *and* public (unsigned) access to get that object's ACL with an S3 bucket policy as follows:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "testing",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetObjectAcl"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/mykey.jpg"
        }
    ]
}
```

To test unsigned access to the ACL, use the awscli as follows:

```
aws s3api get-object-acl --bucket mybucket --key mykey.jpg --no-sign-request
```

However, I would **not** personally recommend exposing the ACL unless you have a strong need to do so as it exposes the object owner and object grants.